# Using Angular typehead on a existing service

Tags: angularjs

Folks,

I am trying to use Angular typehead for auto-complete purpose:

Each object in my mongo collection looks like:

```
{
'name': 'George ow"
'address': "123 lakeshide blvd"
'number': '123-456-790'
'ssn': '123-12345'
...
.. 
}
```

I want to do an-autocomplete on the name field of this collection

My current websservice looks like below. it is used for querying and getting people by id currently.

```
  server.get('/peopleList/:id', function(req, res, next) {

    var _id = collection.db.bson_serializer.ObjectID.createFromHexString(req.params.id);

    collection.findOne({ '_id' : _id}, function(err,data) {
      if (err) {
        throw err;
      }
      res.send( data );
    });

  });
```

My resource that utilizes this webservice looks like:

```
  .factory('PeopleList', ['$resource', function($resource) {
      return $resource(BaseURL + 'peopleList/:_id', {_id: '@_id'}, {} );
    }])
```

In the front-end I have my input box as follows:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="person.name" placeholder="Enter name here" typehead = "">
```

At this point .. I am lost.. how do I connect the remaining dots ?

Comment: I think you're missing a controller that loads data using the service you defined, and gives it to the scope.

Comment: Loremlpsum..I am not quiet sure what to put in the controller .. that's the guidance I am seeking